# How to get the source of an image inside a div using javascript?

Tags: javascript

How can I get the source of an image placed inside a div with unique id.

```
<div id="0a01">
   <img src = "one.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="0a02">
   <img src = "two.jpg" />
</div>
<div id="0a03">
   <img src = "three.jpg" />
</div>
```

I know if I had given an id to the image itself I could've got it using -

```
var src= document.getElementById("<id-for-image>").src;
```

Since I can't give an id to the image tag, that makes it tricky. Not sure how get it in this case?

Comment: Be careful when you use id not valid in HTML4 (for example starting with a digit) : they may be a problem in many cases.

Comment: Roger that. Since you mentioned it, Can you please tell more about it? What can go wrong?

Comment: id, classes and so on are very useful in CSS. Not being able to style your elements because you can't refer to them in CSS is the main thing that can go wrong. Of course Not being able to easily refer to them in DOM selectors isn't good neither.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) :

```
var src= document.querySelector("#id-for-image img").src;
```

Note that the selector must be compatible with the CSS norm. That means that your id must not start with a digit.

If you really can't fix your id (which is bad because it will lead to other problems), then you can use this kind of selector :

```
var src= document.querySelector('[id="0a03"] img').src;
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ISOmer/1/)

Comment: Didn't he say there was no ID for the image...?

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Well... yes. This selector picks the first image that is a descendant of the element with id "id-for-image".

Answer (score 1):

If your layout will always be like that, you can use [.children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children), like:

```
var i = document.getElementById("0a01").children[0].src;
```